# Configuring Route 53 to route traffic to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain name that I registered with a site called [DotEasy](https://www.doteasy.com/). I am building a web app that I am going to host on AWS and I would like to use AWS Route 53 for my DNS. Ideally I'd like to use Route 53 as the registrar as well, but I'm not sure if that's possible and I've also heard it can take ~3 months for domain registrars to switch over.

Either way, I'm trying to set up Route 53 so that when users go to `myapp.example.com` they get routed to a specific EC2 instance of mine.

So I go into Route 53 and clicked **Create Hosted Zone** and Route 53 created two DNS records for me:

- A **NS (Name Server)** record that has 4 different values, all of the form `ns-<X>.awsdns-<Y>.<TLD>`, where `<TLD>` is `.com`, `.net`, `.co.uk`, etc.; and
- A single **SOA (Start of Authority)** record

I'm pretty green when it comes to DNS setup, I'm *hoping* I can just log into DotEasy's admin panel and update `myapp.example.com`'s DNS settings to point to one of these records, but I'm not sure which ones I need to use. DotEasy's UI has fields that allow me to enter/change a primary, secondary, third and fourth DNS server hostname.

So I have two issues here:

1. Configuring Route 53 to route traffic over port 9200 to a specific EC2 instance (ultimately this will be an ECS custer or ELB load-balanced URL but for now its just a single EC2). **I assume I need to write my own Zone file or perhaps Route 53 can create one for me?**; and
2. Configuring DotEasy and/or Route 53 so that requests to `https://myapp.example.com:9200` get forwarded to whatever resource/mapping was created above in Step 1

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

[DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) are different protocols.

After you create an ELB attach your instances and within your DNS provider just create a [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) pointing to the public address of your [ELB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html), for example:

```
myapp IN CNAME elb-nme.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

To respond request on port `9200`, you need to configure the ELB for doing this, but this has nothing to do with the `DNS`.